# Formatting String Using jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

How to format a string in jQuery. i have a json code need to format like this,

```
    "OrigDests": [
            {
                "TotalEllapsedTime": "1.03:45:00",
                "Segments": [
                    {...
```

1.03:45:00 ; i want to replace "." sign into "days" and format the other into hh:mm:ss;

Comment: your time already is "hh:mm:ss" , isn't it?

Comment: this might help you http://jsfiddle.net/qmacro/W54hy/ ,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery

Comment: yup, but i didn't know how to split . character so that i'll format that like this "1day 3hours 45minutes 0second

Comment: use `.split()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var str="1.03:45:00";
var value = str.replace(".", "day ");
alert(value);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VbjKr/

Comment: thanks sir, sir 1 more question; is it possible that this "1.03:45:00" can split and print something like this 1day 3hrs 45mins 0sec

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9pV25/)

```
var x = "1.03:45:00".split('.');
var y = x[0] + ' Day';
var z = x[1].split(':');
var str = y + ' ' + z[0] + 'hours ' + z[1] + 'minutes ' + z[2] + 'second';
console.log(str); //1 Day 03hours 45minutes 00second 
alert(str); //1 Day 03hours 45minutes 00second
```

[.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

[json.stringify()](http://jsfiddle.net/qmacro/W54hy/)

[Serializing to JSON in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to use a format is javascript is to write your own.

```
String.prototype.format = function () {
    var args = arguments;
    return this.replace(/{(\d+)}/g, function (match, number) {
        return typeof args[number] != 'undefined' ? args[number] : match;
    });
};
```

Now after this, formatting can be done like

```
var formatted = "{0} days {1}".format(elapsedTime.substring(0, elapsedTime.indexOf('.')), elapsedTime.substring(elapsedTime.indexOf('.') + 1));
```

You can see the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/achakravarty/zEAW5/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use `replace` function :

```
var str = "1.03:45:00";
str = str.replace('.','day');
```